# How many different names are possible from combining

Tags: combinatorics

There are N cities with N different names. Every city has their own population. The government ended up combining those cities together until only one is left.

It is done by combining any 2 cities at random - and taking the name of one of the 2 cities with the larger population.

How many different names are possible if
a) N=8 and the populations of the 8 cities are 2, 50, 24, 21, 1, 9, 15, 5?
b) N=100 and the population of a city x is x^2?

Comment: It seems there are $N$ ways. In the end only one city name is left, the name of the city with the largest population. If the $N$ different city names are given randomly, then one of the $N$ remains. I put this as a comment rather than an answer because I have a feeling I'm interpreting this incorrectly, so please clarify if this is the case.

Comment: @RandomUser That was my first impression, I believe he means, "How many different names can occur, prior to finishing the combining", example with some of his a) 2, 50, 24,21. Here we can put 2 with 50, 24 and, 21 yielding 3 names(50,24 and 21), next, 50 with 24 and 21, we only get 50, so on... So it is a laddering system.

Comment: OP, is this iterative? We take the first set of pairs(4 pairs) and they are combined as stated, then we now have 4 cities, which are taken to be 2, and then combined?

Comment: @DisplayName I myself am not sure. Could you show how you did it?

Comment: @significantfigure Refer to edit please

Comment: @DisplayName yes, but the pairs are chosen at random

Answer (score 1):

For (a), call the cities $A,B,\ldots,H$ with populations $1,2,5,9,15,21,24,50$.  We will say that city $X$ "absorbs" city $Y$ if combining them gives a city named $X$.  For example $F$ can absorb $E$ giving a population of $36$ for $F$, and this new $F$ can then absorb $G$.

Now $A$ cannot ever absorb any other city so it will lose its name as soon as it is combined.  $B$ can absorb $A$ for a total population of $3$, but then nothing else.  $C$ can only absorb $B$ and $A$ to make a total of $8$, then nothing else.  So these names cannot be the final name.

However all the others are possible.  $D$ can absorb $C,B,A$ giving population $17$; this enables it to absorb $E$, then $F$, then $G$, then $H$, making one city called $D$.  The same goes for those higher on the list.

So there are five possible final names: $D,E,F,G,H$.

Doing (b) in the same way, suppose $A,B,C,\ldots$ have populations $1,4,9,\ldots\,$.  Then $A$ will be absorbed, $B$ can only absorb $A$ for a population of $5$, $C$ can only get up to at most $14$.  But $D$ could absorb $C,B,A$ to get to $30$, then it can absorb $E$, and all the rest one by one.  Once the city with population $x^2$ has been absorbed, the city created has population greater than $2x^2$, which is greater than $(x+1)^2$, so the next city gets absorbed too, and so on.  So all names are possible for the final combined city, except for $A,B,C$.

Comment: On another note, how do you use the mathematical formatting on stack exchange?

Comment: @significantfigure http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @significantfigure are they all paired from the start(in a ladder), or are they randomly picked one pair at a time?